# UISegmentedControl like-menu in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I am currently developing a mobile App in Swift 2 and I am very very new to this. I am trying to create a Login Page that has a toggle button to toggle between the 'Sign Up' and the 'Log In'. (Sorry, I don't have enough rep to upload photos).

It is somewhat similar to Instagram's login page.
I thought it'll be good to use a UISegmentedControl for this. I have create my own SegmentedControl class (with design) to be called.  But faced the following issue:
`Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed`
`Failed to render instance of SegmentedControl: The agent crashed`

This only happens when I call the
`label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "orange_line.png")!)`

What I'm doing here is I'm setting the image as the background for the labels. I can't paste the entire codes here (too long) but I can send you the codes/images if needed!

Not sure if this is the right method or is there another method?

#### Edit: Added Codes

Called this in my viewController class

`
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class SegmentedControl: UIControl {

```
private var labels = [UILabel]()
var thumbView = UIView()


var items: [String] = ["SIGN UP", "SIGN IN"] {
    didSet {
        setupLabels()
    }
}

var selectedIndex : Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        displayNewSelectedIndex()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var selectedLabelColor : UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor() {
    didSet {
        setSelectedColors()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var unselectedLabelColor : UIColor = UIColor.grayColor() {
    didSet {
        setSelectedColors()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var thumbColor : UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
    didSet {
        setSelectedColors()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor : UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var font : UIFont! = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12) {
    didSet {
        setFont()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupView()
}

func setupView(){
    layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
    layer.borderWidth = 0
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    setupLabels()
    addIndividualItemConstraints(labels, mainView: self, padding: 0)
    insertSubview(thumbView, atIndex: 0)
}

func setupLabels(){

    for label in labels {
        label.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    labels.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    for index in 1...items.count {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40))
        label.text = items[index - 1]
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
        label.textColor = index == 1 ? selectedLabelColor : unselectedLabelColor
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(label)
        labels.append(label)
    }

    addIndividualItemConstraints(labels, mainView: self, padding: 0)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var selectFrame = self.bounds
    let newWidth = CGRectGetWidth(selectFrame) / CGFloat(items.count)
    selectFrame.size.width = newWidth
    thumbView.frame = selectFrame
    thumbView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "orange_line.png")!)
    displayNewSelectedIndex()

}

override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    let location = touch.locationInView(self)

    var calculatedIndex : Int?
    for (index, item) in labels.enumerate() {
        if item.frame.contains(location) {
            calculatedIndex = index
        }
    }

    if calculatedIndex != nil {
        selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
        sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

    return false
}

func displayNewSelectedIndex(){
    for (index, item) in labels.enumerate() {
        item.textColor = unselectedLabelColor
        item.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "test.png")!)
    }

    let label = labels[selectedIndex]
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "orange_line.png")!)
    label.textColor = selectedLabelColor

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

        self.thumbView.frame = label.frame

        }, completion: nil)

}

func addIndividualItemConstraints(items: [UIView], mainView: UIView, padding: CGFloat) {

    let constraints = mainView.constraints

    for (index, button) in items.enumerate() {

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        var rightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

        if index == items.count - 1 {

            rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -padding)

        }else{

            let nextButton = items[index+1]
            rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nextButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -padding)
        }


        var leftConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

        if index == 0 {

            leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: padding)

        }else{

            let prevButton = items[index-1]
            leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: prevButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: padding)

            let firstItem = items[0]

            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: firstItem, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0  , constant: 0)

            mainView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        }

        mainView.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint, leftConstraint])
    }
}

func setSelectedColors(){
    for item in labels {
        item.textColor = unselectedLabelColor
    }

    if labels.count > 0 {
        labels[0].textColor = selectedLabelColor
    }

    thumbView.backgroundColor = thumbColor
}

func setFont(){
    for item in labels {
        item.font = font
    }
}
```

}

This was in my viewController class:

`
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    segmentControl.items = ["SIGN UP" , "SIGN IN"]
    segmentControl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: 16)
    segmentControl.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)
    segmentControl.selectedIndex = 1
    segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentValueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

   }
```

`

Comment: Are you using storyboards ?

Comment: Could you post the code of your class? Without seeing it, my recommendation would be to create a separate view for your orange line (guessing thats an underline style indicator?).

Comment: **Akhilesh Sharma**: Yes I am using storyboards, because I am not really good with Swift. 

**@Chris Slowik**: Edited with code. But yes! That is what I was trying to get. It is a Grey underline style indicator when unselected, but turns Orange when selected. Thanks!